# jackson IOException: Can not deserialize Class com.mycompany.models.Person$Address (of type non-static member class) as a Bean

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class Person {
    public class Address {
        private String line1;
        private String line2;
        private String zipCode;
        private String state;

        // standard public getters and setters for the class here
   }

private String name;
private String address;

// standard public getters and setters for the class here

}
```

and here’s how I am using jackson with it.

```
public class JsonTest {
    public static <T> Object fromJson(String jsonAsString, Class<T> pojoClass)
throws JsonMappingException, JsonParseException, IOException {
        return m.readValue(jsonAsString, pojoClass);
    }

    public static String toJson(Object pojo, boolean prettyPrint)
throws JsonMappingException, JsonGenerationException, IOException {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        JsonGenerator jg = jf.createJsonGenerator(sw);
        if (prettyPrint) {
            jg.useDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        }
        m.writeValue(jg, pojo);
        return sw.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Person p = new Person();
         String json = this.toJson(p, true); // converts ‘p’ to JSON just fine
         Person personFromJson = this.fromJson(json, Person.class); // throws exception!!!
    }
}
```

the 3rd line of the main method (where I try to convert json to Person object), throws this exception:

```
IOException: Can not deserialize Class com.mycompany.models.Person$Address (of type non-static member class) as a Bean
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like you can't serialize such classes, see http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/08/entry_411.html for details

Comment: @Stas Kurilin - You should turn that comment into an answer, its the right one.

Comment: @Perception, done. But I hope smb can help ishaq in better way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because inner classes do not have a default zero argument constructor (they have a hidden reference to the outer/parent class) Jackson cannot instantiate them.

The solution is to use `static` inner classes:

```
public class Outer {
    static class Inner {
        private String foo;
        public String getFoo() { return foo; }
    }
}
```

**Original Answer**:

There are some issues in implementation and it seems like you can't serialize such classes, see [cowtowncoder](http://cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/08/entry_411.html) for details.

Comment: I had same problem then I converted my inner class to separate class.

Answer (score 4):

Correct, this used to be something you can not do with current Jackson versions (1.8 and earlier).
But is it absolutely necessary for inner class to be non-static? If not, just add 'static' in declaration of Address and it'll work fine; problem is with the "hidden" this-pointer that non-static inner classes take via constructor.

Jackson 1.9 will actually supports deserialization of simple uses of non-static inner classes, see this [Jira entry](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-594).

Comment: yes, that’s exactly what I did, added ‘static’ to inner class declarations. didn’t know how non-static and static inner classes differed, now I know. thanks.