# Jackson deserialization with anonymous classes

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I have been searching all day for something that answers this, but I have not had a lot of luck thus far.

My question is straightforward: how do I deserialize an anonymous object correctly using Jackson.

```
private interface Interface1
{
    int getValue();
}

public static void testAnonymousObject() throws IOException
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, Visibility.NONE);
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);

    Interface1 testObject = new Interface1()
    {
        private final int value = 5;

        @Override
        public int getValue()
        {
           return value;
        }
    };

    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(testObject);
    System.out.println("JSON = " + json);

    Interface1 received = (Interface1) mapper.readValue(json, Object.class);
    System.out.println(received);
}
```

The output of this is: JSON = ["com.foo.test.JacksonTest$1",{"value":5}] before I get an exception:

*Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize Class com.foo.test.JacksonTest$1 (of type local/anonymous) as a Bean*.

**EDIT** Just to clarify, both Jackson and XStream are able to serialize the object. But only XStream seems to be able to deserialize the object back. So this scenario can be made to work.

Comment: An inner class instance needs an instance of its outer class to be constructed. What would Jackson use? How would it create the outer class instance? What's wrong with top-level classes and static nested classes?

Comment: The object being serialized / de-serialized here is simply an anonymous implementation of an empty interface. 

The issue is that I am converting a large codebase that already uses XStream serialization to use Jackson. Anonymous objects are fairly common in the code. In this case, XStream is able to serialize and deserialize this object. Jackson is only able to serialize,  but cannot deserialize.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of the time I am writing this, it seems that Jackson does not serialize inner classes or anonymous classes correctly. Other packages such as XStream and Kryo, do however.

Comment: You mean Jackson does not _deserialize_ non-static inner classes. Static inner classes are supported.

Answer (score 2):

> Because inner classes do not have a default zero argument constructor (they have a hidden reference to the outer/parent class) Jackson cannot instantiate them.

You can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890796/jackson-ioexception-can-not-deserialize-class-com-mycompany-models-personaddre).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not just about it being an inner class (which may or may not be problematic, depending on whether implementation is static or non-static), but also in that no type information is included -- all Jackson sees is type `Interface1`. To enable reading it back it is necessary to either include type information ("polymorphic type handling"), or to specify mapping between abstract type and implementation class.

Given that you are using an anonymous inner class, you would be able to support this usage by enabled so-called "default typing" (see `ObjectMapper` javadocs for `enableDefaultTyping()` or such).
But you may also need to implement specific strategy, if you do not want to enable type inclusion for all non-final types.

To see whether type id is included you can enable default typing with one of default options and have a look at JSON being produced: there should be an additional type id ("@class" property when class name is used as id).

Comment: I have actually enabled default typing, which is why the JSON, also included in the question, contains the class name "com.foo.test.JacksonTest$1. But I'm not sure how to get the serialized JSON to deserialize correctly (note that it does have the right class name).

Comment: Ah. Then the problem is with anonymous inner class not being static, and requiring so-called "implicit" `this` pointer. This is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

A ready-to-use code-snippet for a generic JSON-deserialization to a Java POJO with Jackson using nested classes:

```java
static class MyJSON {

    private Map<String, Object> content = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setContent(String key, Object value) {
        content.put(key, value);
    }
}

String json = "{\"City\":\"Prague\"}";

try {

    MyPOJO myPOJO = objectMapper.readValue(json, MyPOJO.class);

    String jsonAttVal = myPOJO.content.get("City").toString();

    System.out.println(jsonAttVal);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`@JsonAnySetter` ensures a generic JSON-parsing and population.