# How can I read the user credentials from a JSON login attempt using default classes?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, jwt

I am following a tutorial on [Implementing JWT Authentication on Spring Boot APIs](https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/) and in the key part of the author's JWTAuthenticationFilter class (which is just what it sounds like), he retrieves the username and password from the JSON body of a POST request to a login endpoint.

So, using `curl` or Postman or something, you'd POST to /login with the body of your request containing something like `{"username":"joe", "password":"pass"}`.

The author's authentication filter maps this JSON into an **ApplicationUser** instance with this method:

```
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
    try {
        ApplicationUser creds = new ObjectMapper()
                .readValue(req.getInputStream(), ApplicationUser.class);

        return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        creds.getUsername(),
                        creds.getPassword(),
                        new ArrayList<>())
        );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Good enough, but to do this he's created a custom class **ApplicationUser** as well as a customer UserDetailsService, a UserController, and an ApplicationUserRepository all to work with his own idiosyncratic in-memory database backend.  In my real Spring Boot app, I'm using the default database schema and letting Spring Boot authenticate users via JDBC.  It works great with form authentication.  This is the bit in my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter that does it:

```
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder .jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource);
    }
```

So my question is, how does the `attemptAuthentication` method need to change from the tutorial's code?  I took a guess that the default implementation might be `User.class` and tried to plug it into the expression that imports "`creds`", like this:

```
User creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), User.class);
```

That didn't work.  I get this exception:

```
webapp_1  | 2019-11-22 15:54:43.234  WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] n.j.w.g.config.JWTAuthenticationFilter   : inputstream: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@1477c9d5
webapp_1  | 2019-11-22 15:54:43.298 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
webapp_1  |
webapp_1  | java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

I don't want to just dive into subclassing `User` because I actually don't even know if it's the right class, or if I even need it here.  Can I just extract `username` and `password` from my JSON POST in some other way, maybe bypassing the use of `ObjectMapper()`?  Or should I create a private internal class here?  To sum up, the question is: **How can I best adapt this "`attemptAuthentication`" method while using the default JDBC-based implementation of users in Spring Boot?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works, although I still think that there's got to be a more elegant way of doing it.  What I do is define a static inner class `LoginAttempt` and use `ObjectMapper` to read the JSON as an instance of it.

I found that without the `static` modifier, Jackson cannot deserialize an inner class (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418564/jackson-deserialization-with-anonymous-classes)) but with "`static`" it works.

The relevant code from `JWTAuthenticationFilter` is:

```
static class LoginAttempt {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    public LoginAttempt() {}
    public String getUsername() { return username; }
    public String getPassword() { return password; }
    public void setUsername(String username) { this.username = username; }
    public void setPassword(String password) { this.password = password; }
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    try {
        LoginAttempt creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginAttempt.class);
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        creds.getUsername(),
                        creds.getPassword(),
                        new ArrayList<>()
                )
        );
    } catch( IOException e ) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```